# Overriding IE default CSS for disabled inputs

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

IE 7 applies its own font color to disabled inputs.  How can I override this and set my own font color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your input a class and add the styling via css.

Html:

```
 <input class="dis" disabled="disabled" value="something"></input>
```

CSS

```
.dis{color:red;}
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TQUhD/1

As Diodeus comments :disabled is not supported in IE: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-disabled

Answer (score 4):

IE7 supports the [`[attr]` selector](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html), so you can simply use:

```
input[disabled]
{
  color: red;
}
```

This may cause issues with DHTML (you'll have to try it), in which case you may want to additionally set a class when working on dynamic elements:

```
input.disabled,
input[disabled]
{
  color: red;
}
```

Note that `[attr]` is the "has attribute" selector, there are [a bunch of other selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching) in the CSS spec. Because `disabled` is a [boolean attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes), you only have to check for its existence rather than any particular value.

Answer (score 0):

There is no style for `disabled`. CSS3 supports `:disabled`, but IE7 doesn't.

kmb385's suggestion is probably the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

No need to overrride CSS use class based approach and play with events works perfectly

You can do one thing:
<button class="disabled" onmousedown="return checkDisable();" >

function checkDisable() {

```
    if($(this).hasClass('disabled') { return false;}
```

}