# Change text color for input text in html when it is in disabled in IE8

Tags: css, html

In IE8 it shows up as light gray and is barely readable. Chrome and Firefox are fine . How can i solve it ?

Answer (score -1):

Try using this

```
input[type=text]:disabled
{
  color:red
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since IE7 and above supports the `[attr]` selector, you could do what was [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7126850/394013).

```
input[disabled]
{
  color: red;
}
```

Hopefully that helps. I can't test it since I'm on Windows 7 and only have IE10.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `jQuery`:

```
$('input[type=text]:disabled').css({
    'color' : 'red'
});
```

or `CSS`:

```
input[type=text]:disabled
{
   color:red
}
```

I strongly recommand `CSS` :D